# What can Dataset do which Association and List cannot?

Tags: dataset

Looking at the [documentation page for Dataset](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset.html), I don't seem to find any example which cannot be easily reproduced by a few lines of code involving Association or List. Dataset gives you some convenient syntax, but do you really need a dedicated data structure just for this, beyond the classic data structures used in all sorts of programming languages (arrays, linked lists, hash tables, etc.) which are already supported by other aspects of the Wolfram language? Admittedly my experience is with symbolic math not large-scale data analysis, so maybe there's some workflow I don't appreciate?

Comment: You certainly can do all that `Dataset` allows you to, also with bare lists and associations. In many cases, it will just require more code. Also, since `Dataset` offers a certain abstraction, one can argue that the "bare WL" code will in general be lower level, less declarative and more repetitive / redundant - and this is probably even more important, since this makes the difference qualitative, not just quantitative. That said, the `Dataset` abstraction / model may often not be the most convenient one or not the one optimized for most common use cases - your milage will vary.